# How do I determine the source of a Twitter Bootstrap component event?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, jquery, popover

If I use the tooltip and popover Twitter Bootstrap Javascript components on an element how do I determine which component fired the 'shown' event?

For example:

```
$("#button").tooltip();
$("#button").popover();

$("#button").on("shown", function(event) {
    // I need to do some (flash) stuff that's specific to the popover content,
    // the shown event is fired for both the tooltip and popover but doesn't 
    // appear to include any useful information about the context of the event.

    // How do I determine if the popover component fired the event? The event.target
    // is useless because it points to #button.
    // The best I've come up with is to check if the element I'm interested in 
    // is visible but I'm assuming this will have issues if the popover component
    // is animated...
    if ($(".popover .thingy").is(':visible')) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it uses jQuery, I believe the current element that event represents is simply:

```
this
```

Or,

```
$(this) // to do jQuery operations on it
```

If you want to check if it is visible:

```
if ($(this).is(":visible")) { ... }
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Based on previous experience I assume that `this` would refer to "#button"...

Comment: Yes it would... I thought that was what you were looking for, if not, then "this" will not work.  You are looking for the POPOVER element that gets shown then, not the element that triggered the popover, correct?

Comment: Yeah, I need to know when the popover is shown (NOT the tooltip). It looks like Bootstrap is using '#button' as the source of the event (event.target == '#button') so `this` refers to the button. I was hoping for a property on event that would indicate what is being shown (like event.popoverCreatedThisEvent).